# How to remove submit button from jqGrid edit form

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid Edit form invoked using Edit button from top toolbar is defined as

```
      grid.navGrid("#grid_toppager", { del: false,add: false,view: true }, 
      { url: '/Edit',
            bSubmit: 'Save',
            editCaption: 'Change',
        } );
```

This is used to show data in readonly grid. Pressing submit button does not make sence in this case.
How to remove submit button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide Submit button the in the `beforeShowForm` of the edit form options:

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    $form.parent().find('#sData').hide();
}
```