# jqGrid Modal Form Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a populated jqGrid; my code includes the following block to display the double-clicked record in a modal form.  The form, by default, includes 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons.  How can I remove the 'Submit' button?

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) 
{
    jQuery("#data").jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid);
}
```

I basically need a "read-only" form for easier viewing of the records in the grid.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377625/how-to-remove-submit-button-from-jqgrid-edit-form did not work

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing but also looked at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing for a solution with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct your requirements you should use [viewGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#viewgridrow) instead of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow). All fields are included per default in the form. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewFormOnDoubleClick1.htm) do what you want (I hope):

[image]

It uses the following code

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("viewGridRow", rowid, { caption: "Details of the invice" });
}
```

By the way you can specify [viewable: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) property in `colModel` to remove content of the column from the View form. The demo

Comment: The viewGridRow method is exactly what I need, thanks!